# AnimateWindow Slide

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I want my form slide down and back to position with slide animation, how to make correct AnimateWinows, if it real for sure ...

```
void __fastcall TUsers::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
if (!pressed)
{
        Height=700;
        //AnimateWindow(Handle, 500, AW_CENTER | AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_POSITIVE);
        pressed=true;
}
else
{
        pressed=false;
        //AnimateWindow(Handle, 500, AW_CENTER | AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_NEGATIVE);
        Height=425;
}
}
```

to moderators : here is no mutters Builder or Delphi :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in controlling the animation yourself, here is a sample of code we wrote to accomplish that. It looks and works great. We are sliding Tform1 from the right to the left within a TPanel control on the main form. We ensure that Self.Parent and DoubleBuffered gets set correctly in MyCreate. ShiftLeft and then ShiftRight do the work. We ran into a problem for certain users where the Self.Top was being shifted so we are making sure that Self.Top := 0 with each iteration and when fully shifted. That solved all of the weird issues we were seeing.

Hope this helps!

```
{
  TForm1.MyCreate
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
constructor TForm1.MyCreate(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  OwnerControl: TWinControl;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  if Owner is TWinControl then
  begin
    OwnerControl := Owner as TWinControl;
    Self.Parent := OwnerControl;
  end;

  Self.Visible := false;
  Self.DoubleBuffered := true;
  Self.BorderStyle := bsNone;

end;

{
  TForm1.ShiftLeft
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TForm1.ShiftLeft;
var
  TicksStart: int64;
  InitLeftValue: integer;
  StartLeftValue: integer;
  NewLeftValue: integer;
  LeftValueDif: integer;
  RemainingTicks: int64;

begin
  Self.Top := 0;
  Self.Height := Self.Parent.ClientHeight;
  Self.Width := Self.Parent.ClientWidth;

  InitLeftValue := Self.Parent.Left;
  StartLeftValue := Self.Parent.Left + Self.Parent.ClientWidth;
  LeftValueDif := StartLeftValue - InitLeftValue;

  Self.Left := StartLeftValue;
  Self.Visible := true;

  TicksStart := GetTickCount();
  RemainingTicks := FadeTime;

  while RemainingTicks > 0 do
  begin
    NewLeftValue := (LeftValueDif * RemainingTicks) div FadeTime;
    Self.Left := Max(InitLeftValue, NewLeftValue);
    Self.Parent.Repaint;
    Self.Top := 0;
    Self.Repaint;

    RemainingTicks := FadeTime - int64(GetTickCount - TicksStart);
  end;

  if Self.Left > InitLeftValue then
    Self.Left := InitLeftValue;

  Self.Parent.Repaint;
  Self.Top := 0;
  Self.Repaint;
end;

{
  TForm1.ShiftRight
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
procedure TForm1.ShiftRight;
var
  TicksStart: int64;
  StartLeftValue: integer;
  EndLeftValue: integer;
  NewLeftValue: integer;
  LeftValueDif: integer;
  RemainingTicks: int64;

begin
  Self.Top := 0;
  StartLeftValue := Self.Left;
  EndLeftValue := Self.Left + Self.Width;
  LeftValueDif := EndLeftValue - StartLeftValue;

  TicksStart := GetTickCount();
  RemainingTicks := FadeTime;

  while RemainingTicks > 0 do
  begin
    NewLeftValue := (LeftValueDif * (FadeTime - RemainingTicks)) div FadeTime;
    Self.Left := Max(StartLeftValue, NewLeftValue);
    Self.Parent.Repaint;
    Self.Top := 0;
    Self.Repaint;

    RemainingTicks := FadeTime - int64(GetTickCount - TicksStart);
  end;

  if Self.Left < EndLeftValue then
    Self.Left := EndLeftValue;

  Self.Parent.Repaint;
  Self.Top := 0;
  Self.Repaint;
end;
```

Comment: FadeTime is a constant we set to 300.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what `AnimateWindow` is for. That function hides or shows a window using some animation. Your window is already visible, and you want it to stay visible, so `AnimateWindow` is not for you.

What you should do instead is make your window successively taller or shorter in a loop until you reach the new desired height.

Comment: Hm... I think I sow some example when AnimateWindow works with a frames... I think I need to separate somehow my form for a two frames and then use slide somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately AnimateWindow works only with windows (aka TForms), not with child windows (aka TFrames and TControls).

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link for an answer and a cool demo program.

http://delphi.about.com/od/delphi-tips-2011/qt/hide-slide-fade-away-controls-delphi-form.htm